# Getting at Json variables

Tags: json, variables

I have the following json data:

```
var JSONObject2= {
    "weather": {
        "curren_weather": [
            {
                "humidity": "69",
                "pressure": "1012",
                "temp": "70",
                "temp_unit": "f",
                "weather_code": "1",
                "weather_text": "Mostly cloudy",
                "wind": [
                    {
                        "dir": "Not Available",
                        "speed": "0",
                        "wind_unit": "mph"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "forecast": [
            {
                "date": "2012-08-21",
                "day": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "0",
                        "weather_text": "Sunny skies",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "NW",
                                "dir_degree": "311",
                                "speed": "7",
                                "wind_unit": "mph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "day_max_temp": "83",
                "night": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "0",
                        "weather_text": "Clear skies",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "WNW",
                                "dir_degree": "289",
                                "speed": "7",
                                "wind_unit": "mph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "night_min_temp": "57",
                "temp_unit": "f"
            },
            {
                "date": "2012-08-22",
                "day": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "0",
                        "weather_text": "Sunny skies",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "N",
                                "dir_degree": "7",
                                "speed": "4",
                                "wind_unit": "mph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "day_max_temp": "85",
                "night": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "0",
                        "weather_text": "Clear skies",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "S",
                                "dir_degree": "176",
                                "speed": "7",
                                "wind_unit": "mph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "night_min_temp": "63",
                "temp_unit": "f"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

On very simple json data, I can figure out how to get at the variables. On something like the above, it is difficult for me.

So to access say where the temp is 70, I would code:
var my_temp= weather.curren_weather.temp  // This does not work

So just as 2 examples how would I get at the temp(70)  and say where the wind_degree is 311?

Also is there a program where you can paste in the json object like the above and it will output the correct code needed to access any variable?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object *is* complicated by the nested arrays, and it's unclear why *current weather* requires a nested array.

To get at the `temp` of 70 given this structure, you'll need:

```
var temp = JSONObject2.weather.curren_weather[0].temp;
```

And for that particular wind reading:

```
var wind = JSONObject2.weather.forecast[0].day[0].wind[0].dir_degree;
```

For the `forecast` field, the nested array is reasonable, since you're given a list of forecasts for different datesm and so the daytime wind reading for the second date represented in your data can be extracted using:

```
var wind = JSONObject2.weather.forecast[1].day[0].wind[0].dir_degree;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The object is straight from a weather site that returns json data. I was hoping for a program that could get at say every variable and then show the code needed to do so. This might be a good project for someone.